# Cannot post form data via HTML/JavaScript/Express Node app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to build an app that lets me enter in information about an event and then have that pinned on a map. I'm stuck at the beginning though on actually saving the information. When I use Inspect in Chrome, it tells me it posted, but the data is blank. I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff and not sure where I'm going wrong.

The first file is the app.js where I set up the database, a simple partial schema, etc.

The second file is my dashboard.html that displays the map and the form. I was trying the onsubmit/javascript stuff which displays the data without refreshing the page, but ideally I want to be able to refresh the page and have the data still be posted somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

```js
require('dotenv').config({ silent: false }); // Retrieve .env contents

var http = require('http');      // Basic HTTP functionality
var path = require('path');      // Parse directory paths
var express = require('express');    // Provide static routing to pages
var app = express();
var Router       = require('router')
var router = Router()

var server = http.Server(app);
var port = 8080;
var app = setupExpress();

// Import mongoose module and connect the database
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://Username:Password@ds159180.mlab.com:59180/app-database';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);

//Get the default connection
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Start server on port 8080
// localhost:8080
server.listen(port);

//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));


//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var EventSchema = new Schema({
    eventName          : String,
    eventType          : String
});
var Event = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);

app.post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body); // req.body is your form data
});

app.post('/dashboard', function(req,res){
var content = new Event({
  eventName : req.body.eventName,
  eventType : req.body.eventType
}).save(function(err,doc){
    if(err){
      return handleError(err);
    } else {
      console.log('your form has been saved');
    }
  })
});

function setupExpress()
{
 // Set default path for views and public
 var viewsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
 var publicDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

 app.use(express.static(publicDir));

 // Root page is login form
 app.get('/', function(req, res)
 {
  res.sendFile('views/index.html', { root: '.' });
 });

 // Once logged in, home page is dashboard
 app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res)
 {
  res.sendFile('views/dashboard.html', { root: '.' });
 });

 // Redirect to error page if there's an issue
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next)
 {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(err.status || 500);

  res.sendFile('/views/error.html', { root: '.' });
 });

 return app;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Web browser tab title -->
  <title>App</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
  <link href="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="../css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
  <link href="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://www.your-domain.com/easy-comment/jquery.easy-comment.min.js"></script>


  <title>App Tester</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
     #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8"  style="margin-top: 30px">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-3x"> Add Event</i>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <form id="eventForm" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="eventName">Event Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventName" placeholder="Event name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="eventType">Type</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="eventType">
                        <option>Study Group</option>
                        <option>Food</option>
                        <option>Meeting</option>
                        <option>Danger</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="eventLocation">Location</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="eventLocation">
                        <option>Location 1</option>
                        <option>Location 2</option>
                        <option>Location 3</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="eventNotes">Event Notes</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="eventNotes" rows="2" placeholder="Add details about your event"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>

                <div id="confirm"><div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                  var txt = document.getElementById("eventName");

                  document.getElementById("eventForm").addEventListener("submit", confirmdata);

                  function confirmdata(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var eventName = txt.value;

                    document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML += '<p>Name: ' + eventName + '</p>';

                  }
                </script>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to change your data post from client to json

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

You can get json data via  `req.body`

Comment: Would I use the req.body like this: `app.post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body); 
});`?

Or should it be app.get? I'm confused on how to view this data once it's been submitted too.